# Extract data from c++ string

Tags: c++

I wanted to extract the values from the string in C++. I guess this is not the C++ way of doing this, but that one in particular doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
string line = "{10}{20}Hello World!";
int start;
int end;
string text;

// What to use here? Is the sscanf() a good idea? How to implement it?

cout << start; // 10
cout << end; // 20
cout << text; // Hello World!
```

Comment: look at `std::cin` and string streams

Comment: Cin is to get values from 'keyboard', no?

Comment: Look up std::string::substr and/or std::regex

Comment: I know about substr, but it is pretty annoying/ugly to work with :/ Also, have had some problems with the pointers on that one :(

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of how to use regex in this particular example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can make `sscanf` work, this solution is more appropriate for C programs. In C++ you should prefer [string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
string s("{10}{20}Hello World!");
stringstream iss(s);
```

Now you can use the familiar stream operations for reading input into integers and strings:

```
string a;
int x, y;
iss.ignore(1, '{');
iss >> x;
iss.ignore(1, '}');
iss.ignore(1, '{');
iss >> y;
iss.ignore(1, '}');
getline(iss, a);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/IgPL7y)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the method String.find() to get the positions of '{' and '}' and then extract the data you want through String.substr().

Answer (score -2):

text does not need to have an "&" in front of it inside the sscanf, since string names are already pointers to their starting address.

```
sscanf(line, "{%d}{%d}%s", &start, &end, text);
```

Comment: I get:
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') [-Wformat]

Comment: @RajeevSingh My bad. I have edited the question without notice. It is still relevant :)